# Delphi drag and change position/order of a component

Tags: delphi, controls, move

I have a main panel aligned to the the top and in that panel i create another panels which i use as buttons which are aligned to the left (and when i create the button panels the button panel that last created is at the right end)

I use main panel as a container and other panels as a button, i want to be able to drag and change the order the button panels in the main panel and i also want to be able to drag a panel outside of the container panel and place it in the form

How can i do that draging and changing order the panels in the main panel and drag them out of the main panel?

Comment: Have you read documentation concerning to drag/drop abilities? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.DragMode

Comment: Yes i checked on drag/drop operations and i think i need to use drag/drop to move the panel outside of the main panel but i dont know how to move them right/left and reordering the panel in the moved position (and slide the other panels left/right according the position of the moved panel)

Answer (score -1):

How to Move and Resize Controls at Run Time (in Delphi Applications) 
[enter link description here](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-move-and-resize-controls-at-run-time-4092542)